# Sort array by its content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I have an array looking like this:

```
markerArray[i] = [i, title, cat];
```

this array is within a for loop adding the content dynamic

so the result could be something like this:

```
markerArray[0] = [0, A title, A];
markerArray[1] = [1, A title new, B];
markerArray[3] = [3, A title, E];
markerArray[4] = [4, A title, A];
```

So my question is how can I or is it possible to sort the array so that the output would be based on A,B C etc or title or whatever taken from inside the array like this, note that the last (category) is in alphabetic order now:

```
    markerArray[0] = [0, A title, A];
    markerArray[1] = [4, A title, A];
    markerArray[2] = [1, A title new, B];
    markerArray[3] = [3, A title, E];
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377730/javascript-arrays-sorting/7377824#7377824

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try -

```
var markerArray = new Array();
markerArray[0] = [0, "A title", "A"];
markerArray[1] = [1, "A title new", "B"];
markerArray[3] = [3, "A title", "E"];
markerArray[4] = [4, "A title", "Z"];
markerArray[5] = [5, "A title", "A"];


markerArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   var comp1 = a[2];
   var comp2 = b[2];
   return (comp1 < comp2) ? -1 : (comp1 > comp2) ? 1 : 0;
})

alert(markerArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the **sort** function, available in the Array object.
This function/method accepts a custom user function to determine how the elements have to be sorted.

```
function customSorter( a, b )
{
    var comp1 = a[2];
    var comp2 = b[2];
    return (comp1 < comp2) ? -1 : (comp1 > comp2) ? 1 : 0;
}
var markerArray = new Array();
markerArray[0] = [0, "A title", "A"];
markerArray[1] = [1, "A title new", "B"];
markerArray[3] = [3, "A title", "E"];
markerArray[4] = [4, "A title", "Z"];
markerArray[5] = [5, "A title", "A"];

markerArray.sort( customSorter );
```

Useful info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom sort function. Read a [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the compare function as a parameter to Array.sort method and write your comparison logic inside the compare function. See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You could try this kind of stuff:

```
   markerArray.sort(function(a,b){ 
      for (i = 0; i <= 3 ; i++) {
         if (a[i] <> b[i]) {
            if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
            if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
         }
      }
      return 0;
   });
```

This will try to sort with the first element, if they are identical, it tries to sort with the second one, and so on with the third one.

[EDIT] Adding some interesting links (see other answers too):

- [What is the easiest way to order a <UL>/<OL> in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-order-a-ul-ol-in-jquery)
- [How may I sort a list alphabetically using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134976/how-may-i-sort-a-list-alphabetically-using-jquery)
- http://hungred.com/how-to/tutorial-sort-array-javascript/